# Prove that $z = tx + (1 − t)y$ if $d(x, y)= d(x, z) + d(z, y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, plane-curves

Let $x,y,z$ be elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$
Prove that $z = tx + (1 − t)y$ if $d(x, y)= d(x, z) + d(z, y)$ 
d is usual euclidean metric.

Comment: What metric $d$?

Comment: Usual euclidean

Comment: Not sure if one needs to choose one.

Answer (score 0):

What can we use about the usual metric?

**Heron's formula**... If the sides of a triangle are $a,b,c$, then the area
of the triangle is
$$
A=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}
$$
Now if $a=b+c$, then that area is zero.

Comment: I am looking for an algebraic proof. This is geometric